# Html Agility Pack get specific content from a div

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to pull text from a "div" and to exclude everything else. Can you help me please ?!

```
<div class="article">
   <div class="date">01.01.2000</div>
   <div class="news-type"><a href="../link/page01">Breaking News</a></div>

   "Here is the location of the text i would like to pull"

</div>
```

When I pull "article" class i get everything, but i'm unable/don't know how to exclude class="date", class="news-type", and everything in it.

Here is the code i use:

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'article')]"))
{
    name_text.text += node.InnerHtml.Trim();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be using XPath `/text()[normalize-space()]` to get *non-empty*, direct-child text nodes from the `div` elements :

```
var divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'article')]");
foreach (HtmlNode div in divs)
{
    var node = div.SelectSingleNode("text()[normalize-space()]");
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/55rYG2)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
"Here is the location of the text i would like to pull"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. If i may ask one more question. If i  have multiple <div class="article"> ? How can i list all off them? How would a loop look like?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want the ChildNodes that are type HtmlTextNode. Untested suggested code:

```
var textNodes = node.ChildNodes.OfType<HtmlTextNode>();
if (textNodes.Any())
{
    name_text.text += string.Join(string.Empty, textNodes.Select(tn => tn.InnerHtml));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.